# What is the general solution to a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a equation

$$y''+\alpha y'+\beta y = f(x)$$

Characteristic equation should be

$$\lambda^2 + \alpha\lambda + \beta = 0$$
$$\lambda = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
$$where \ a=1, b=\alpha, c=\beta$$

If my general solution is given to be
$$y_h = e^{3x}(C_1 \sin 4x + C_2 \cos 4x)$$

Does that mean that 
$$3= \frac{-b}{2a}$$
$$4i = \frac{\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$$

Please explain, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Say a Characteristic equation $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$ has solutions $p\pm iq$. The Imaginary component must come from the discriminant being *negative* i.e. $b^2-4ac<0$.

So by equating both sides (the solution itself and the generic solution of a Quadratic equation),

$$
p\pm iq = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$

you *can* assert that

$$
\text{Re}\left(p\pm iq\right) = -\frac{b}{2a}
$$

and

$$
\text{Im}\left(p\pm iq\right) =\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{{2a}}
$$

provided that $b^2-4ac<0$.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of solution is obtained when the auxiliary equation obtained has complex roots. Say, $p+iq$ and $p-iq$. Now, the general solution of the homogenous DE is  $Ae^{(p+iq)x}+Be^{(p-iq)x}$. Now, since $e^{iqx}=cos qx+isinqx$, we have the solution as $e^{px}(C_1cosqx+C_2sinqx)$ where, $C_1=A+B $ and $C_2=i(A-B)$. Now, let's go back to  the equation: $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$. You have $p=-b/a$ and $p^2+q^2=c/a$. Now, can you figure it out from here..